# mognoose searching with regular expression in multiple columns

Tags: regex, node.js, mongoose

I have a mongoose model with schema defined as -

```
var campusNotesSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    noteId:{type:String, unique:true, default: uuid.v4()},
    title: {type:String, required:'{PATH} is required!'},
    uploader:{type:String,required:'{PATH} is required!'},
    department:{type:String},
    college:{type:String},
    author:{type:String,required:'{PATH} is required!'},
    actualFileName: [String],
    storedFileName: [String],
    subject: {type:String},
    description: {type:String},
    details: {type:String},
    date: {type:Date, default: Date},
    tags: [String]
});
```

and the model defined as -

```
var Campusnotes = mongoose.model('Campusnotes', campusNotesSchema);
```

Now I want to search in the title, tags, description field from the request objects parameters something like

```
if(req.query.searchText){        
    Campusnotes.find({title:new RegExp(searchText,'i'),description:new RegExp(searchText,'i')}).exec(function(err, collection) {
        res.send(collection);
    })
}
```

Now how do i make sure that any results in which the term is found in either title or description is also included and not only the ones which are there in both of them.
Also, how do i search in the tags array for the matching strings

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can user **$or** operator in mongoose to return results with either of matches
**$or** http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/

```
Campusnotes.find({'$or':[{title:new RegExp(searchText,'i')},{description:new RegExp(searchText,'i')}]}).exec(function(err, collection) {
    res.send(collection);
})
```

To search in array for matching strings, you need to use $in operator of mongo:

**$in** : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

Comment: according to the manual I need the array that I want to look in, but I don't have the tags array as it is in the database. so how do i make my query to search for some text in an array that is stored in database

Comment: $in operator works as follows: `{ field: { $in: [<value1>, <value2>, ... <valueN> ] } }` where, field is an entity of a document stored in the database. Manual clearly states that if **field** is an **array** the $in operator selects the documents whose field holds an array that contains at least one element that matches a value in the specified array (e.g. <value1>, <value2>, etc.). For your use case, field is **tags** array, and the right side array contains only one value,i.e., the string you want to search for.

Answer (score 2):

use this query ,$option = i, will skip the lower /upper case 
when you are inserting data into TAG array first make it lowercase and search with lowercase this would be easy.

```
Campusnotes.find({title:{'$regex':searchText,'$option':'i'},description:{'$regex':searchText,'$option':'i'},tags:searchText}, function(err, collection){
res.send(collection);
});
```